# В чем разница между «вырастить» и «воспитать»?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Откройте секрет: как **воспитать** такую чудесную внучку?
>
> Откройте секрет: как **вырастить** такую чудесную внучку?

Интересно, чем по смыслу и употреблению один отличается от другого?

Answer (score 2):

Синонимы, но разница в оттенках смысла.

Вырастить внучку — упор на физическое (довести до взрослого состояния), но включает в себя и воспитание. В вашем примере говорится о результате, поэтому "вырастить" не очень подходит, если внучка еще маленькая.

Воспитать внучку - вырастить ее, воздействуя на ее духовное и физическое развитие. Если внучка еще маленькая, означает "привить, внушить ей какие-л. чувства, развить навыки".

> [ВОСПИТАТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20), -аю, -аешь; воспитанный; -тан, -а, -о; св. 1. кого (кем, каким). Вырастить (ребёнка), воздействуя на его духовное и физическое развитие; дать образование, привить навыки поведения в обществе, сформировать характер или его отдельные черты. В. гражданина. В. творческую личность. В. борцом за справедливость. В. добрым, скромным, мужественным. 2. что. Привить, внушить кому-л. какие-л. чувства, развить навыки. В. чувство ответственности. В. уважение к старшим. В. вкус. <Воспитывать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Воспитываться, -ается; страд.
>
> [ВЫРАСТИТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20), -ращу, -растишь; выращенный; -щен, -а, -о; св. (нсв. растить) 1. кого. Заботясь о ребёнке, довести до взрослого состояния; воспитать каким-л. В. трёх дочерей. В. сына здоровым и жизнерадостным. * Не та мать, которая родила, а та мать, которая вырастила (Погов.). 2. кого-что. Обучая и воспитывая, подготовить к какой-л. деятельности. В. научные кадры. В. себе достойную смену. В. рекордсмена. 3. кого-что. Ухаживая, обеспечить рост, развитие. В. телёнка. 4. что. Создавая условия для роста, развития, получить что-л. В. искусственный кристалл. В. богатый урожай. В. сад. <Выращивать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Выращиваться, -ается; страд. Выращивание, -я; ср.